# Prove if $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow C$, and $g \circ f$ is one-to-one, then $f$ is one-to-one?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Prove if $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow C$, and $g \circ f$ is one-to-one, then $f$ is one-to-one?

My professor stated my proof is wrong but I'll state it anyway.

If $g \circ f$ is one-to-one, then if $x\neq y$, $g(f(x))\neq g(f(y))$. Hence $f(x)\neq f(y)$ (I now know this is wrong). Hence if $x\neq y$, $f(x)\neq f(y)$. Hence f is one-to-one.

What is the correct proof? I couldn't find it in the answer key and couldn't understand the version online. Try to state it as simply as possible.

Comment: It is not as nice, perhaps,  as a proof with less negations...but I can't see any mistake in what you did.

Comment: hint:  suppose the contrary.  That is, suppose there are two distinct elements in $A$ with $f(a_1)=f(a_2)$.  Derive a contradiction.

Comment: @Arbuja Taking into account what Lulu wrote, it may be that if you wrote in your paper exactly as you wrote in your question:  $\;g(f(x))\neq g(f(y))\implies f(x)\neq f(y)\;$ that you assumed $\;g\;$ is injective...and perhaps he expected you to write down clearly that $\;g\circ f(x)\neq g\circ f(y)\implies...\;$ and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your work is correct, but I'd go as follows: suppose we have $\;x,y \in A\;$ s.t. $\;f(x)=f(y)\;$ (we must prove then that $\;x=y\;$ ). But then

$$g\circ f(x)=g(f(x))=g(f(y))=g\circ f(y)\stackrel{\text{because we assume }\;g\circ f\;\text{is}\;1-1}\implies\;\;x=y$$

and we're done.